# Getting same base url based for vue and apache reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue app i am testing out using pm2 with apache. Once pm2 has started the app and the app is running on port 3000, i then use apache reverse proxy to make use of a domain and https. However, i would like to get the same base_url in when i need to make use of the base url.

Currently,i am getting the base_url like this

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
```

When used inside a vue app, this always returns `localhost:3000` but since the url has been changed by proxy, the new url returned should be `mydomain.com`

How would i detect the app is now handling requests using a proxy and return the correct base_url in vue?

My Apache conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


ServerAdmin info@mydomain.com


ServerName mydomain.com


ServerAlias www.mydomain.com


DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyVia Full

<Proxy *>

Require all granted

</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com [OR]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.com

RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you running your app as SSR?

Comment: No, just ordinary spa app.

Comment: Can you post nginx config?

Comment: Its just the ordinary location block `server_name mydomain.com

location / {
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/;
    }`

Comment: That's why you are not getting the real address. Let me post the config.

Comment: On this cluster i am using apache `ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Please check my answer and post those configs.

Comment: I have updated with my complete apache conf. I have apache and nginx clusters but its the apache i need at the moment but if the same idea applies for nginx, then i can reuse.

Comment: I updated my answer, so basically you will need to pass the same nginx headers in apache, you can follow the docs to get it working. Else headers are same for both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell nginx to pass the url down to your vue app. You will need to use something like this (`nginx.conf`):

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

These are some required headers to make it working.

Or if you are using Apache, you can add this directive `ProxyPreserveHost On` and it will work.